# How to create a vector containing a (artificially generated) Guassian (normal) distribution?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, statistics

If I have data (a daily stock chart is a good example but it could be anything) in which I only know the range (high - low) that X units sold within but I don't know the exact price at which any given item sold.  Assume for simplicity that the price range contains enough buckets (e.g. forty one-cent increments for a 40 cent range) to make such a distribution practical.  How can I go about distributing those items to form a normal bell curve stored in a vector?  It doesn't have to be perfect but realistic.

My (very) naive thinking has been to assume that since random numbers should form a normal distribution I can do something like have a binary RNG.  If, for example, there are forty buckets then if a '0' comes up 40 times the 0th bucket gets incremented and if a '1' comes up for times in a row then the 39th bucket gets incremented.  If '1' comes up 20 times then it is in the middle of the vector.  Do this for each item until X units have been accounted for.  This may or may not be right and in any case seems way more inefficient than necessary.  I am looking for something more sensible.

This isn't homework, just a problem that has been bugging me and my statistics is not up to snuff.  Most literature seems to be about analyzing the distribution after it already exists but not much about how to artificially create one.

I want to write this in c++ so pre-packaged solutions in R or matlab or whatnot are not too useful for me.

Thanks.  I hope this made sense.

Comment: "My (very) naive thinking has been to assume that since random numbers should form a normal distribution" - This is really not true. You CAN use algorithms to generate values from a normal distribution (indeed from many many statistical distributions) however.

Comment: Is it possible that what you are trying to do is create a histogram of a Gaussian distribution with frequency counts for each bin stored as elements of a vector??

Comment: Why not use the Boost random generators library?  Or the new C++11 random library?

Comment: See the [Boost.Random docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) - the C++11 version should be the same, but in the `std` namespace.

Comment: As an aside, it seems to me the binomial distribution would be a better fit to your problem. The binomial is "roughly" normal shaped, but fits your model of buckets better than the normal, because it represents a probability over a set of discrete values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Most literature seems to be about analyzing the distribution after it already exists but not much about how to artificially create one.

There's tons of literature on how to create one. The Box–Muller transform, the Marsaglia polar method (a variant of Box-Muller), and the Ziggurat algorithm are three. (Google those terms). Both Box-Muller methods are easy to implement.

Better yet, just use a random generator that already exists that implements one of these algorithms. Both boost and the new C++11 have such packages.

Comment: Leave it to Boost!  After a quick looks this seems like it will do what I need.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm that you describe relies on the Central Limit Theorem that says that a random variable defined as the sum of `n` random variables that belong to the *same* distribution tends to approach a normal distribution when `n` grows to infinity. Uniformly distributed pseudorandom variables that come from a computer PRNG make a special case of this general theorem.

To get a more efficient algorithm you can view probability density function as a some sort of space warp that expands the real axis in the middle and shrinks it to the ends.

Let F: R -> [0:1] be the cumulative function of the normal distribution, invF be its inverse and x be a random variable uniformly distributed on [0:1] then invF(x) will be a normally distributed random variable.

All you need to implement this is be able to compute invF(x). Unfortunately this function cannot be expressed with elementary functions. In fact, it is a solution of a nonlinear differential equation. However you can efficiently solve the equation x = F(y) using the Newton method.

What I have described is a simplified presentation of the *Inverse transform method*. It is a very general approach. There are specialized algorithms for sampling from the normal distribution that are more efficient. These are mentioned in the answer of David Hammen.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.  It may take me the remainder of the summer to fully appreciate your answer but I look forward to the payoff.